# Responsive WebDesign Questions

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Ok so today I said hey, let's learn us some Responsive Web Design Techniques. So far so good I suppose ;)

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #avacweb_chat{
    height: 70%;
    width: 600px;
    }
 }
@media screen and(min-width:600px) {
  #avacweb_chat{
    height: 70%;
    width: 540px;
    }
 }
@media screen and(min-width:480px) {
  #avacweb_chat{
    height: 500px;
    width: 320px;
    }
  #chatbox_members{
    display:none;
    }
 }
@media screen and(min-width:320px) {
  #avacweb_chat{
    height: 360px;
    width: 220px;
    }
 #chatbox_members{
   display:none;
    }
}
```

I wanted to ask a few question to some of my great S.O. members, so I see the media query is focused on screen is there anyway to do this

```
 @media #avacweb_chat and (min-width: 500px) {

   }
```

Or are we only allowed to focus on screen size? Also are we allowed to use transitions and transform in these media queries? (I know IE won't support). these are the only two questions I have.

Focusing on size of another element besides Screen
  Adding CSS3 to the queries.

Comment: Try validating and see what happens?  Better yet, check the w3c:  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: This is true, but problem is, that I have active members and this is only site I can test on. So I figured I'd ask, didn't need a downvote from whomever. These are valid questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also are we allowed to use transitions and transform in these media queries?

Yes, for sure. Simply include them as you normally would

> is there anyway to do this

```
@media #avacweb_chat and (min-width: 500px) {

 }
```

Not sure what you are getting at here. If your goal here is to cusomise the avacweb_chat div for viewports above 500px, use

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
#avacweb_chat{
/* some styles here */
}

}
```

If you are just getting your feet wet with responsive design, have you considered some of the options like [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) or one of the many other good choices. They aren't necessarily for everyone, but they'll get you off to a fast start.

Have fun with RWD!

Comment: Thank you david, as you atleast can understand just getting into something and wanting to know things, and I don't use other things like Bootstrap or Foundation, its just a small project dealing with an iframe chat so I'm trying to make it responsive. Thank you